# swipe gesture is not smooth for frame jumping

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have made an as3 android app where I have used swipe gesture for going next frame and previous frame. but I want when I jump to next or previous frame it swipes smoothly.I have tried to use tween max but it is not working.I have found that tween plugins always work for movie clips.So how can I make the swipe smooth.Can I make it smooth without tween plugins?here is my code....

```
Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.GESTURE;
stage.addEventListener (TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_SWIPE, SwipeHandler);
function SwipeHandler(event:TransformGestureEvent):void
{
   switch(event.offsetX)
   {
      // swiped right
      case 1:
      {
        prevFrame();
        break;
      }

     // swiped left
     case -1:
     {
        if(currentFrame == 10) 
        {
          stop();
        }
        else
        {
          nextFrame();
          break;
        }
      }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

In order for you to be able to smooth swap you need to have both frames on your screen, which is not the case with genuine Flash frames. Smooth transitions are animated via `ENTER_FRAME` handlers, with a potential hide of actual frame change process. So, in order to do a smooth transition, you need to move a picture of one frame to the left, and for the other frame to move in from the right instead of plain `nextFrame()`. Let's say you have a 60fpa stage, and try to smooth transition left. You will need two screen-sized objects, one depicting current frame and one the frame to be displayed, ready to be displayed as a single transition. An example:

```
var transition:Sprite;
var bitmaps:Array;
var leftSide:Bitmap
var rightSide:Bitmap;
// initialization code, best placed in constructor
leftSide=new Bitmap();
rightSide=new Bitmap();
bitmaps=[];
transition=new Sprite();
transition.addChild(leftSide);
transition.addChild(rightSide);
rightSide.x=stage.stageWidth; //left side and right side should be aside each other
```

This is the declaration of the needed structures. The plan is to show the `transition`, giving it two `Bitmap`s that will be linked to two different `BitmapData` objects that'll hold pictures of new frame and old frame. We will draw our current frame on current frame's bitmapdata, then take a stored next frame bitmap data and the do transition.

```
function swipeHandler((event:TransformGestureEvent):void {
    var doSwitch:Boolean=false;
    var targetFrame:int=currentFrame;
    switch(event.offsetX) {
        // swiped right
        case 1: {
            if (currentFrame>2) {
                // let's say we're not allowed to swipe right from frame 2
                targetframe=currentFrame-1;
                doSwitch=true;
            }
            break;
        }
        // swiped left
        case -1: {
            if(currentFrame < 10) {
                targetFrame=currentFrame+1;
                doSwitch=true;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!doSwitch) return;
    // prepare transition
    if (!bitmaps[targetFrame]) bitmaps[targetFrame]=new BitmapData(stage.stageWidth,stage.stageHeight,false,0xffffff);
    // ^ make a new bitmap if there's none for target frame
    if (!bitmaps[currentFrame]) bitmaps[currentFrame]=new BitmapData(stage.stageWidth,stage.stageHeight,false,0xffffff);
    // the same for source frame
    bitmaps[currentFrame].fillRect(bitmaps[currentFrame].rect,0xffffff); 
    bitmaps[currentFrame].draw(stage); // draw current frame on the bitmap
    // with this and stored bitmaps, old frame would remain drawn on the cached bitmap
    // and able to be used as a transition image
    if (targetFrame>currentFrame) { 
        leftSide.bitmapData=bitmaps[currentFrame];
        rightSide.bitmapData=bitmaps[targetFrame];
        transition.x=0;
        // here is the place to initialize TweenMax tween to move "transition"
        // and don't forget to removeChild(transition) at the end of the tween
    } else {
        rightSide.bitmapData=bitmaps[currentFrame];
        leftSide.bitmapData=bitmaps[targetFrame];
        transition.x=-1*stage.stageWidth;
        // same here for tweening
    }
    stage.addChild(transition);
    gotoAndStop(targetFrame);
}
```

This places a prepared `transition` object on screen above all the underlying items, effectively masking the exact frame switch, done by `gotoAndStop()` call. This object's `x` coordinate can be tweened afterwards, and the object should be removed from stage once the tween is ofer.

Hope this helps.